# Laravel Eloquent selecting primary key 'could not be converted to string'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have a route where a user input the player_id which is a foreign key in PlayerWife table:

```
Route::get('player/wife/{player_id}','WifeController@showWife');
```

Then in WifeController inside the showWife function I put:

```
public function showWife($player_id)
{
    $playerWife = PlayerWife::where('player_id',$player_id);
    return $playerWife;
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

What is the correct way to select the PlayerWife by player_id with eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I need to add firstOrFail() like this:

```
$playerWife = PlayerWife::where('player_id',$player_id)->firstOrFail();
```

And it solved the problem.